# Viscous damping in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, waves, gravitational-waves, viscosity, dissipation

In Minkowski spacetime, waves are modeled via the wave equation $$(\partial_t^2-\Delta)u=0.$$ When viscous damping is present, one studies the damped wave equation
$$(\partial_t^2-\Delta+W(x)\partial_t)u=0,$$ where $W\geq 0$ is the damping function. On more general spacetimes $(\mathbb{R}^4,g)$ (we'll take the signature $(+---)$), the wave equation becomes $$|g|^{-1/2}\partial_\alpha |g|^{1/2}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta u=0.$$ Are there any applications of the natural/simplest analogue of the damped wave equation in the general Lorentzian setting, i.e.
$$|g|^{-1/2}\partial_\alpha |g|^{1/2}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta u+W(x)\partial_t u=0?$$

Comment: Even in Minkowski spacetime, you could do a coordinate transformation which would make a term like $W\partial_t u$ appear in the wave equation in those new coordinates.

Comment: @Andrew That seems somewhat artificial. I'm talking specifically about the presence of the damping force.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly artificial, in the sense that the term you are interested in comes from a coordinate transformation, but also illustrates a key subtlety in GR. There are many different representations of the same physics, related by coordinate transformations. It's important to ask about properties that are invariant under coordinate transformations, if you want the answer to a physical question. Tying the effect you are interested in to this term in a differential equation is therefore not a good way to think about the underlying physical effect, because it is coordinate dependent.

Comment: However, your example is reminiscent of [Hubble drag](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Bertschinger/Bert1_3.html) in cosmology (although again this is a coordinate dependent effect).

Comment: @Andrew understood, thank you!